# Javascript Function Still Not Working.. Tests and Failed

Tags: javascript, html

The first javascript function switchText() works fine and swap the texts as desired, but the second javascript function switchTextx() does not work at all except for the alert() function.

The second function looks identical to the working function switchText(). I've ensure there is no tag conflict but still now working.

What is the root of the problem and how can i get the second function switchTextx() to work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        ...Test
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="sample"></h1>
    <button id = "buttonc" type="button" value="swap text" onclick="swithText()" >Toggle Text</button>
    <hr>
    <h1 id="samplex"></h1>
    <button id = "buttoncx" type="button" value="swap text" onclick="swithTextx()" >Toggle Text</button>

    <footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function swithText() {
        alert('function running');

     var theTogglex = document.getElementById("buttonc");
     var toggleMex = document.getElementById("sample"); 
            toggleMex.toggleStatusx = "on";

            theTogglex.onclick = function(){
        switch(toggleMex.toggleStatusx){
                case "on":
                            toggleMex.toggleStatusx="off";
                            toggleMex.textContent = "I CHANGED MY CLOTHES ONE TIME";
            break;

                case "off":
                            toggleMex.toggleStatusx="on";
                            toggleMex.textContent = "2ND CHANGE TODAY!";
                  }
                }
            }




        function swithTextx(){
            alert('function running');


            var toggleButtonr = document.getElementById("buttoncx");
            var contentSampler = document.getElementById("samplex");
            toggleButtonr.toggleStatusr = "on";

            toggleButtonr.onclick = function(){
                switch(contentSampler.toggleStatusr){
                    case "on":
                                contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "off";
                                contentSampler.textContent = "I CHANGED MY CLOTHES ONE TIME";

                    break;

                    case "off":
                                contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "on";
                                contentSampler.textContent = "2ND CHANGE TODAY!";


                }
            } 
        } 

    </script>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages at all?

Comment: No errors. Just not functioning as desired. The alert() works fine

Comment: The second switch statement should it not be switch(toggleButtonr.toggleStatusr)

Comment: @sjdm actually its supposed to be contentSampler.toggleStatusr="on"

Comment: Surely the button should be the one which has its value toggled "on" and "off" the content should be only toggling the text ? that would make more sense programaticaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `toggleButtonr.toggleStatusr = "on";` near the start of your `switchTextx()` function. You need to change it to `contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "on";` to allow your switch statment to get activated initially.

See working example below:

```js
function swithText() {
  alert('function running');

  var theTogglex = document.getElementById("buttonc");
  var toggleMex = document.getElementById("sample");
  toggleMex.toggleStatusx = "on";

  theTogglex.onclick = function() {
    switch (toggleMex.toggleStatusx) {
      case "on":
        toggleMex.toggleStatusx = "off";
        toggleMex.textContent = "I CHANGED MY CLOTHES ONE TIME";
        break;
      case "off":
        toggleMex.toggleStatusx = "on";
        toggleMex.textContent = "2ND CHANGE TODAY!";
    }
  }
}




function swithTextx() {
  alert("function running");
  var toggleButtonr = document.getElementById("buttoncx");
  var contentSampler = document.getElementById("samplex");
  contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "on";

  toggleButtonr.onclick = function() {
    switch (contentSampler.toggleStatusr) {
      case "on":
        contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "off";
        contentSampler.textContent = "I CHANGED MY CLOTHES ONE TIME";

        break;

      case "off":
        contentSampler.toggleStatusr = "on";
        contentSampler.textContent = "2ND CHANGE TODAY!";


    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    ...Test
  </title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="sample"></h1>
  <button id="buttonc" type="button" value="swap text" onclick="swithText()">Toggle Text</button>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="samplex"></h1>
  <button id="buttoncx" type="button" value="swap text" onclick="swithTextx()">Toggle Text</button>

</body>
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help